# Add/Remove of products to cart in listview

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to make a Restaurant's menu with ordering feature. There is a simple listview which has product name, price and add, remove buttons. What I want is when a user clicks on the "ADD" button, the product name and price gets added to an arraylist or something so that I can fetch this list in another activity and display the total price. I can use SQLite for storing the items but then I don't know how to get the price of each selected product (in 2nd activity) for adding. Is there any particular way to store items for this like using POJO and adapter?

```js
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView listView;
    private ArrayList<Model> mListData;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

        mListData = new ArrayList<>();

        mListData.add(new Model("Beef Manhattan", "50"));
        mListData.add(new Model("Chicken Fried Steak", "90"));
        mListData.add(new Model("Corned Beef", "100"));
        mListData.add(new Model("Domesticated Turkey", "80"));
        mListData.add(new Model("Eggs Benedict", "10"));
        mListData.add(new Model("French Dip", "20"));
        mListData.add(new Model("Green Bean Casserole", "30"));
        mListData.add(new Model("Potato Salad", "40"));
        mListData.add(new Model("Pumpkin Pie", "60"));
        mListData.add(new Model("Salisbury Steak", "70"));

        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, R.layout.listrow, mListData);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

}
```

```css
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model> {

    private Context mContext;
    int resource;
    private ArrayList<Model> mListData = new ArrayList<Model>();


    public CustomListAdapter(Context mContext, int resource, ArrayList<Model> mListData) {
        super(mContext, resource, mListData);
        this.resource = resource;
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mListData = mListData;
    }

    public void setListData(ArrayList<Model> mListData) {
        this.mListData = mListData;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return super.getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (v == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();

                v = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);

                holder.name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
                holder.rate = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.rate);
                holder.add = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.add);
                holder.remove = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.remove);


            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }




        Model item = mListData.get(position);

            holder.name.setText(item.getName());
            holder.rate.setText(item.getRate());

        return v;
    }

    class ViewHolder {

        TextView name;
        TextView rate;
        Button add;
        Button remove;
    }

}
```

```html
public class Model {

    private String name, rate;

    public Model(String name, String rate) {
        this.name = name;
        this.rate = rate;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getRate() {
        return rate;
    }

    public void setRate(String rate) {
        this.rate = rate;
    }


}
```

Comment: http://www.androiddom.com/2011/06/android-shopping-cart-tutorial-part-2.html

Comment: You don't know how to use SQL SUM statement?

Comment: @cricket_007. No, haven't used it till now. Can you give me some example as I'll be fetching db items to listview.

Comment: `Select sum(price) as total from cart`

Comment: This is my database code http://hastebin.com/mojoduyugi.java @cricket_007

Comment: Thank you? Is there a question to go with that? I told you how to get the sum of the prices already. Are you having problems implementing that?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I got the result using the SUM query as per your suggestion and now its working. @cricket_007

Answer (score 0):

**This may help you**

Create a boolean variable isSelected in your model class and assign initial val as false, when he selects the row or click on add make isSelected variable of that object to true. And pass that ArrayList of object to second activity ,and use a foreach or for loop and ckeck for isSelected , if isSelected is true then get the ammount and add. Thats it. Give a try it will work:)

Comment: I also use same approach but it kinda feels not the best way :D

Comment: Its work well for small ammount of data, in case there is more than 1MB data the intent cannot take that weight and application may crash, so need to consider that case, if in case there is big ammount of data u need to pass, then its better store that result statically and access through singleton class.

Comment: @Somnath Pal did u get the solution?

Comment: My data is coming from web service and yes the data is a bit much. So I guess storing in db works for me as a permanent solution @NaveenShriyan

Comment: Ok if the data is too heavy then its better store in the DB or else follow the above approach as i said, if u need any guidance on that feel free to ask..:) yemmy happy coding..

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying the DB way first @NaveenShriyan

Comment: Sure :) @SomnathPal